# D template called with either expression or typename (DLang)

Tags: templates, d

I'm trying to call a D template and call `.sizeof` on the passed argument, which ideally could either be a typename (or type expression), or a variable name or expression (which of course also has a type).

I've currently had to duplicate the template, like so

```d
template mytem( alias T ) { xxx T.sizeof xxx }

template mytem( T ) { xxx T.sizeof xxx }
```

How do I do things properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, from what you have there, the first template *almost* works without needing the second one. For instance, this code

```d
struct S
{
    int i;
}

template size(alias T)
{
    enum size = T.sizeof;
}

void main()
{
    pragma(msg, size!10);
    pragma(msg, size!S);
    pragma(msg, size!(S(10)));
}
```

prints

```
4LU
4LU
4LU
```

However, it won't work with built-in types - e.g. `size!int` wouldn't compile. The problem is that `alias` parameters are supposed to accept symbols, whereas the built-in types such as `int` are keywords rather than symbols. It's my understanding that after some discussion, Walter Bright was convinced that it should be changed so that `alias` parameters work more like `alias` statements, and they would accept the built-in types, but that change hasn't been made yet. The workaround in the meantime is to use a variadic template but restrict it to a length of 1. e.g.

```d
struct S
{
    int i;
}

template size(T...)
    if(T.length == 1)
{
    enum size = T[0].sizeof;
}

void main()
{
    pragma(msg, size!10);
    pragma(msg, size!S);
    pragma(msg, size!(S(10)));
    pragma(msg, size!int);
}
```

prints

```
4LU
4LU
4LU
4LU
```

Comment: Many thanks once again for your help - you spotted precisely the use-case where things all came unravelled. Let's hope this gets fixed so these kludges won't be necessary.